# Can't create content with DataTemplate in code behind with control defined in xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I have the following label in a ResourceDictionary in xaml of my ContentPage:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
            <Label Text="I am label" x:Name="label" x:Key="label"/>
       </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPaget.Resources>
```

And in in my code behind I have this clicked event handler:

```
void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => label);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
        {
            Label content = (Label) dataTemplate.CreateContent();
            stack.Children.Add(content);
        }
    }
```

In my StackLayout called stack - only 1 label is added when the button assigned with Handle_Clicked is pressed. Why is only 1 label added - when there should be 3 labels added?

Comment: You are using Resources in the wrong way. Waht do you need from the label. Its text then create a string instead and refer to it in your control.  read this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/better-resource-organization-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that all controls need a unique id. Since this was not working either:

```
void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
    {
        stack.Children.Add(label);
    }
}
```

which had brought me to try and use `DataTemplate` in the first place. Meaning the same object can only be added once to the view.

It can also be noted that `createContent()` works - but only if it is being defined in xaml (not being instantiated in code behind):

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="dataTemplate" x:Key="dataTemplate">
                <Label Text="I am label"/>
            </DataTemplate>
       </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPaget.Resources>
```

---

The workaround I found was to get rid of the DataTemplate and [clone](https://github.com/AlenToma/FastDeepCloner) the object instead before adding it:

```
void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
    {
        var l = FastDeepCloner.DeepCloner.Clone(label);
        stack.Children.Add(l);
    }
}
```